# ExtJs Tab Panel Question

Tags: javascript, user-interface, forms, extjs

I have a few tabs in a tab panel with similar forms. How do I prevent going to the next tab unless the previous tab is correctly filled? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your approach is not the best, if you want to create a wizard you should probably use the [cardlayout](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.layout.CardLayout).

If you really want to stick with your current approach, I would hook the `beforetabchange` event and cancel the event if the form are not valid.

i.e.

```
tabpanel.on('beforetabchange', function(tb,newtab,oldtab){
  // insert your validation here
  // if the user cannot go here
  return false; // would prevent the change of tab
});
```